# How to send custom command to terminal?

Tags: vim, macvim

Say, I want to run "echo hello" when I press `<leader>T`

How can I write the script?

Is there any way to do it nicely?

I'm thinking about creating a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
:!echo hello
```

and reading in the contents of a shell command (in this case the `ls` commnand):

```
:r !ls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this command:

```
nnoremap <leader>T :!echo hello<cr>
```

Or, if you don't care about the output:

```
nnoremap <leader>T :silent !echo hello<cr>
```

You can put this in your `.vimrc` so that the mapping is set on startup.

I have some commands that I want to run on the current file.  If you want to save any changes first, and then pass the file name as an argument, you can do it like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>T :update<cr>:!cat '%:p'<cr>
```

where `'%:p'` expands to the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a command using 'command'. e.g. add this to your .vimrc:

```
" define command Hello:
command! Hello echo 'hello world'
```

Then you can run this command in command mode:

```
:Hello
```

To see more complicated examples, just run `:verbose command COMMAND_NAME` to find its definition. e.g. run:

```
:verbose command NERDTree
```

It tells me NERDTree command is defined in .../nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim, then you can find how NERDTree command is defined.